# Object required: Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a button on excel that can mail merge the data in excel into word docuements. So when it runs to the line

```
Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(c.Cells(529, 6).Value)
```

as footnoted in the code, it has a bug of

> "Run-time error'424' object required".

I have already create and put the needed docuement in the path of `c.cells(529 .6)` but it just does not work.

Other wdocSource work just fine, it can mail merge the data into the word docuement specified in path of c.cells, such as c.cells(48, 6).

Here is some of the code. Others are just repeating similar stuff but on different condition, so no gonna show it here otherwise, it would be very long.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set c = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Path")
Dim i As Integer

i = 2
Do Until Cells(i, 3) = ""

If Cells(i, 2) = "N" Or Cells(i, 2) = "n" Or Cells(i, 2) = "E" Or Cells(i, 2) = "e" Or Cells(i, 2) = "+" Then
 
 Dim wd As Object
    Dim wdocSource As Object

    Dim strWorkbookName As String
    ' Word constants
    Const wdFormLetters = 0, wdOpenFormatAuto = 0
    Const wdSendToNewDocument = 0, wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1, wdDefaultLastRecord = -16

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    'path = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("path").Cells(1, 1)
    
    If Cells(i, 2) = "N" Or Cells(i, 2) = "n" Then
    If Cells(i, 31) = 1 Then
    
        If Cells(i, 5) = "A" Or Cells(i, 5) = "B" Or Cells(i, 5) = "C" Or Cells(i, 5) = "D" Or Cells(i, 5) = "E" Then
            Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(c.Cells(48, 6).Value)'this and others work just fine

        ElseIf Left(Cells(i, 5), 24) = "F" Or Left(Cells(i, 5), 17) = "G" Then
            Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(c.Cells(529, 6).Value) '**The mentioned error occurs here**.

        'repeating code...

        End if
    End if
    End if
End if

    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

    wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
            Name:=strWorkbookName, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [A$] where NO=" & i - 1
            
  With wdocSource.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    wd.Visible = True
    wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wdocSource = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing

Else
    
End If

i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Please help!!

Comment: And what is the value of `c.Cells(529, 6).Value` when you get the error?

Comment: Are you sure that `ThisWorkbook` is what you want instead of `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but why are you opening and closing Word inside the loop? Seems very inefficient.

Comment: `c.Cells(529, 6).Value` is the location of the word docuement, e.g. C:\ABC\PX\

Comment: if `c.Cells(529, 6).Value` is just a path, you cannot *Open* it.

Comment: @FunThomas But how come it can open the word docuement in c.Cells(48, 6).value while it can not do the same thing in c.Cells(529, 6)??

Comment: @braX I'm not sure what is the difference between `ActiveWorkbook` and `This Workbook`

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is broken and so I cannot tell the content of you cells or if they point to valid files on your computer. Write the value of the cells into a variable and check the content with the debugger. Check if you can manually open the file with word. Check if the `wd`-object is set.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+activeworkbook+thisworkbook